# ps: show mysql user/database

Tags: linux, mysql

Recently mysql started loading very high cpu. the process is like that:

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/ --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/lib/mysql/vps.err --open-files-limit=8192 --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/vps27.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --port=3306
```

Is there a way to find out which mysql user/database is currently behind that process?

Comment: You won't get that sort of data from the process listings. You will need to use the MySQL Administrator (end of life) or the MySQL workbench to see which user/database is is executing queries during the high CPU loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [mytop](http://jeremy.zawodny.com/mysql/mytop/) to determine what threads are exhausting your cpu.

If mytop is not an option, use `mysqladmin` to show the `processlist`, and look for threads that is running slow transactions: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/thread-information.html

Comment: the point is that they are not slow. all the queries on a page take max 0.01 seconds to load. i just don't know why so much cpu is used